# Gulp build faild

Tags: build, gulp

I am getting problem with running Anguler 1.2 app with gulp, throws following error. Build was developer by some other developer and i am not good at it.

I tried to run npm install, bower update.
Nothing worked.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Please take a look at following error output and code.

Thanks.
    events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

```
Error: watch /home/web/src/ ENOSPC
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
  at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
  at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
  at Gaze._watchDir (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:289:30)
at /home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:358:10
at iterate (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
at Object.forEachSeries (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:66:3)
at Gaze._initWatched (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:354:10)
at Gaze.add (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:177:8)
at new Gaze (/home/web/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:74:10)
```

--Gulp File--------------------------

```
var Gulp = require('gulp');
var Less = require('gulp-less');
var Path = require('path');
var JShint = require('gulp-jshint');
var Browserify = require('browserify');
var Sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var Source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var MinifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');  
var RunSequence = require('run-sequence');

/**
 * HTML template task + watch
 */
Gulp.task('templates', function () {
    // Get our index.html
    // find options here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-html
    var opts = {};

    Gulp.src('src/index.html')
        // And put it in the public folder
        //  .pipe(MinifyHTML(opts))
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/'));

    Gulp.src('src/index.php')
        // And put it in the public folder
        //  .pipe(MinifyHTML(opts))
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/'));

    // Any other view files from src/templates
    return Gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.html')
        // Will be put in the public/templates folder
        //  .pipe(MinifyHTML(opts))
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/templates/'));
});
Gulp.watch(['src/index.php', 'src/index.html', 'src/templates/**/*.html'], {interval: 500}, [
    'templates'
]);


/**
 * LESS / CSS task + watch
 */
Gulp.task('css', function () {
    return Gulp.src('src/css/*.css*')
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('./public/css'));

});
Gulp.watch(['src/css/*.css*'], {interval: 500}, [
    'css'
]);

Gulp.task('less', function () {
    return Gulp.src('src/css/less/*.less')
        .pipe(Sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(Less({
            paths: [Path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')]
        }))
        .pipe(Sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
Gulp.watch(['src/css/**/*.less'], {interval: 500}, [
    'less'
]);

/**
 * Images task + watch
 */
// Image "copy" / "optimize" task
Gulp.task('images', function () {
    // Get our images
    return Gulp.src('src/img/**/*')
        // Do some optional image processing here, such as optimizing
        // And put it in the dist folder
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/img/'))
});
Gulp.watch(['src/img/**/*'], {interval: 1000}, ['images']);

/**
 * Font task + watch
 */
Gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    // Get our fonts
    return Gulp.src('src/fonts/**/*')
        // Do some optional image processing here, such as optimizing
        // And put it in the dist folder
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/fonts/'))
});
Gulp.watch(['src/fonts/**/*'], {interval: 1000}, ['fonts']);

/**
 * JS tasks + watches
 */
// linting
Gulp.task('lint', function () {
    return;
    Gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(JShint())
        // You can look into pretty reporters as well, but that's another story
        .pipe(JShint.reporter('default'));
});

// Browserify task
Gulp.task('l10n', function () {
    return Gulp.src('src/js/l10n/*.js')
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/js/l10n/'));
});

// Browserify task
Gulp.task('browserify', function () {

    var b = Browserify({
        basedir: './',
        entries: './src/js/main.js',
        debug: true,
        insertGlobals: true
    });
    b.transform('deamdify');
    /*  b.transform({
     global: true
     }, ngAnnotate);*/

    /*   b.transform({
     global: true
     }, uglifyify);*/

    return b.bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            // print the error (can replace with gulp-util)
            console.log(err.message);
            // end this stream
            this.end();
        })
        .pipe(Source('bundle.js'))
        // .pipe(streamify(rename({suffix: '.min'})))
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
Gulp.task('javascript', ['lint'], function () {
    // Watch our scripts
    Gulp.watch(['src/js/*.js', 'src/js/**/*.js'], {interval: 500}, [
        'lint',
        'browserify',
        'l10n'
    ]);
});

/**
 * Copy vendor JS
 */
Gulp.task('vendor', function () {
    // Get our images
    return Gulp.src('src/vendor/**/*')
        // Do some optional image processing here, such as optimizing
        // And put it in the dist folder
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('public/vendor/'));
});
Gulp.watch(['src/vendor/**/*'], {interval: 2000}, ['vendor']);

/**
 * default task, start with "gulp"
 */
Gulp.task('default', ['css', 'less', 'images', 'javascript', 'templates', 'fonts', 'vendor'], function () {
    // we depend on 'watch' tasks, so nothing to do really
});


Gulp.task('build', function () {
    RunSequence(
        'css',
        //'less',
        'images',
        'browserify',
        'l10n',
        'templates',
        'fonts',
        'vendor',
        function(){
            console.log('Build completed, closing');
            process.exit(0);
        });
});
```

Comment: looks like following line fails

    Gulp.watch(['src/index.php', 'src/index.html', 'src/templates/*.html'], 
    {interval: 500}, [
        'templates'
    ]);
    Fails at this :  'src/templates/*.html'

Comment: What  command are you running when you get this error? gulp build? gulp?